# Making the number of rows in Angular mat-table longer than the length of dataSource

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular2-directives, mat-table

Is it possible to have a **mat-table** that outputs more rows of data than the length of the provided dataSource? For example with this kind of data:

```
people: [
   { 
      name: "John", 
      birthday: "01.01.2000", 
      hobbies: [
            {type: "Golf", level: "Intermediate"},
            {type: "Bowling", level: "Noob" },
            {type: "Programming", level: "Beginner"}
      ]
   },
   { 
      name: "Linda", 
      birthday: "21.12.2001", 
      hobbies: [
            {type: "Hockey", level: "Elite"},
            {type: "Dart", level: "Noob" },
            {type: "Programming", level: "Intermediate"}
      ]
   }

]
```

Where I use the **people** list as dataSource (i.e. length 2) to mat-table, but I want to generate a table like this:

| Name | Birthday | Hobby | Level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 01.01.2000 | Golf | Intermediate |
| John | 01.01.2000 | Bowling | Noob |
| John | 01.01.2000 | Programming | Beginner |
| Linda | 21.12.2001 | Hockey | Elite |
| Linda | 21.12.2001 | Dart | Noob |
| Linda | 21.12.2001 | Programming | Intermediate |

The code I got so far is like this (although provided data is just sample data):

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
   <ng-container mathColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCell> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let col">{{ col.name }}</mat-cell>
   </ng-container>
   <ng-container mathColumnDef="birthday">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCell> Birthday </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let col">{{ col.birthday }}</mat-cell>
   </ng-container>

   // the next two columns is where the problem lies. 
   // I only getting the first hobby in list to have a valid code.
   <ng-container mathColumnDef="hobby">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCell> Hobby </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let col">{{ col.hobbies[0].type }}</mat-cell> 
   </ng-container>
   <ng-container mathColumnDef="level">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCell> Level </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let col">{{ col.hobbies[0].level }}</mat-cell> 
   </ng-container>
   <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['name', 'birthday', 'hobby', 'level']">
   <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['name', 'birthday', 'hobby', 'level']"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

where dataSource is the person list. Also, the list of hobbies can have different lengths.

I've tried:

- adding a ***ngFor** directive on mat-cell, but it does not allow two structural directives on the same element
- I've also tried a ***ngFor** directive on an ng-container inside the mat-cell element, like this:

  ```
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let col">
       <div>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let item of col.hobbies">
             {{ item.type }}
          </ng-container>
       </div>
    </mat-cell>
  ```

but this did not create the wanted result, that is new table rows for every element in the hobby list.

Does anyone have a solution to this? maybe without the need to create a new list in the component that holds all hobbies as a new list item (i.e. 3 duplicates of name and birthday for John, and 3 duplicates for name and birthday for Linda).

Appreciate all the help I can get

Comment: Maybe this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54293513/how-to-always-display-two-types-of-rows-in-angular-material-table

Answer (score 2):

You can use @iamentaafaz suggestion which gives a material collapsible table display.

But if you want to use the exact type in the question, you might need to refractor the `datasource`.

For the ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

export interface TableData {
  name: any;
  birthday: any;
  type: any;
  level: any;
}

@Component({
  selector: "table-basic-example",
  styleUrls: ["table-basic-example.css"],
  templateUrl: "table-basic-example.html"
})
export class TableBasicExample implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ["name", "birthday", "type", "level"];
  dataSource: any = [];

  people = [
    {
      name: "John",
      birthday: "01.01.2000",
      hobbies: [
        { type: "Golf", level: "Intermediate" },
        { type: "Bowling", level: "Noob" },
        { type: "Programming", level: "Beginner" }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Linda",
      birthday: "21.12.2001",
      hobbies: [
        { type: "Hockey", level: "Elite" },
        { type: "Dart", level: "Noob" },
        { type: "Programming", level: "Intermediate" }
      ]
    }
  ];
  destructuredPersonData: any[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    const destructuredPersonData = this.refractorPeopleData(this.people);
    this.dataSource = destructuredPersonData;
  }

  private refractorPeopleData(data: any[]) {
    let result: TableData[] = [];
    data.forEach(person => {
      const name = person.name;
      const birthday = person.birthday;
      person.hobbies.forEach((hobby: { type: any; level: any }) => {
        if (hobby) {
          const type = hobby.type;
          const level = hobby.level;
          result.push({
            name,
            birthday,
            type,
            level
          });
        }
      });
    });
    return result;
  }
}
```

You can see the demo here https://angular-k5ps1y.stackblitz.io